# Cassandra add column after particular column

Tags: cassandra, cql, alter

I need to alter the table to add a new column after a particular column or as last column, I have been through the document but no luck.

Comment: What is "*to add a new column to particular column*" supposed to mean?

Comment: it is a Cassandra concept @PM77-1

Comment: @PM 77-1 - I have edited the question, I need to add new column after some existing column.

Comment: Why do you want this? If column isn't partition or clustering key order doesn't matter... I think what you want is no possible.

Answer (score 9):

Let's say I'm starting with a table that has this definition:

```
CREATE TABLE mykeyspace.letterstable (
    column_n TEXT,
    column_b TEXT,
    column_c TEXT,
    column_z TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (column_n));
```

1- Adding a column is a simple matter.

```
ALTER TABLE mykeyspace.letterstable ADD column_j TEXT;
```

2- After adding the new column, my table definition will look like this:

```
desc table mykeyspace.letterstable;

CREATE TABLE mykeyspace.letterstable (
    column_n TEXT,
    column_b TEXT,
    column_c TEXT,
    column_j TEXT,
    column_z TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (column_n));
```

This is because columns in Cassandra are stored by ASCII-betical order, after the keys (so `column_n` will always be first, because it is the  only key).  I can't tell Cassandra that I want my new `column_j` to go after `column_z`.  It's going to put it between `column_c` and `column_z` on its own.

Answer (score 3):

Cassandra will store table data based on partition & clustering key.

Standard CQL for adding column:

```
ALTER TABLE keyspace.table ADD COLUMN column1 columnType;
```

Running DESC table for a given table via CQLSH does not portray how the data is stored. It will always list the partition key & clustering key first; then the remaining columns in alphabetical order.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/alter_table_r.html

[Cassandra create table won't keep column order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34072768/cassandra-create-table-wont-keep-column-order)